# Global Variable in safari extension

Tags: javascript, safari, global-variables, safari-extension

How can i have a global variable in **safari extension** that can be acceded from injected script, 
and can be saved for the next launch after safari is closed.

and by global i mean static.

so that all injected script access the same version of that variable not every injected script has it's own.

and not like **localStorage** that is per domain.

Comment: Safari doesn't support accessing things in the global scope from page scopes (injected scripts) and vice versa. You have to use [Messages](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW1) to share things between these scopes. But every page can get a copy of the same thing from the global scope, which should fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Safari extension settings API](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/tools/conceptual/safariextensionguide/ExtensionSettings/ExtensionSettings.html) might be the best thing to use for this. This works similarly to localStorage and is accessible via `safari.extension.settings`.

However, this isn't accessible directly from injected scripts, so you have to [use messages to pass data from a global page](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/tools/conceptual/safariextensionguide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html).

Something like this in your injected script:

```
safari.self.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);

safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage('getSetting', 'myVar');

function handleMessage(msg) {
    if (msg.name === 'returnSetting') {
        var setting = msg.message;
    }
}
```

And in your global page:

```
safari.application.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);

function handleMessage(msg) {
    if (msg.name === 'getSetting') {
        var setting = safari.extension.settings(msg.message);
        safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.page.dispatchMessage('returnSetting', setting);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could do more or less the same thing with localStorage within the domain of the global page, so it isn't restricted to web pages of one domain.

Comment: thanks you very much, but when i close safari and reopen it, will this variable keep it's last value ??

Comment: Yes. Extension settings persist between sessions.

Comment: thanks man, sorry i was away lately, i used your solution and searched for it in safari developer docs in [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/tools/conceptual/safariextensionguide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html)

Comment: @MattSwain I'm currently attempting to access localStorage inside the global page's included JS file `background.js`.  I'm inspecting that file using extension builder and when I try to access localStorage in the console at a set breakpoint it seems to be empty.  Any ideas on how I can access the localStorage for all sites?